# call media_sideload_image in new directory

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to call media_sideload_image as part of an import from an XML feed but i havent had much luck at all - it is currently in a directory (localhost/wordpressdirectory/wordpress/wp-admin/imports) but i keep getting a no such directory error when it tries to contact any of the required files.

See code below which is basically copied from the WP guide for media_sideload_image:

```
<?php 
define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__));

echo ABSPATH . '\wp-admin\includes\plugin.php';
require_once( ABSPATH . '\wp-admin\includes\plugin.php');
require_once( ABSPATH . '\wp-admin\includes\media.php');
require_once( ABSPATH . '\wp-admin\includes\file.php');
require_once( ABSPATH . '\wp-admin\includes\image.php');

$url = "http://s.wordpress.org/style/images/wp3-logo.png";
$post_id = 1;
$desc = "The WordPress Logo";

$image = media_sideload_image($url, $post_id, $desc);
?>
```

I have echoed this and it comes up with this which is not a valid file path:
C:\wamp\www\wordpressdirectory\wordpress\wp-admin\imports\wp-admin\includes\plugin.php

How can i fix this in localhost ideally without hard referencing any requirements to their physical location since abspath seems to be returning an incorrect value?

Answer (score 0):

You define ABSPATH in the plugin above so ABSPATH = 'C:\wamp\www\wordpressdirectory\wordpress\wp-admin\imports' since that is the location your file is in. Using the same code you posted, try going up a directory in your path include like this:

```
<?php 
define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__));

echo ABSPATH . '\..\includes\plugin.php';
require_once( ABSPATH . '\..\includes\plugin.php');
require_once( ABSPATH . '\..\includes\media.php');
require_once( ABSPATH . '\..\includes\file.php');
require_once( ABSPATH . '\..\includes\image.php');

$url = "http://s.wordpress.org/style/images/wp3-logo.png";
$post_id = 1;
$desc = "The WordPress Logo";

$image = media_sideload_image($url, $post_id, $desc);
?>
```

Comment: The reason i defined ABSPATH in that top line is because when it is removed it seems that Wordpress functions and predefined constants are not usable in this directory, it returns this: 'Use of undefined constant ABSPATH - assumed 'ABSPATH'

Am i supposed to also reference something else in the top to get to use these?

Comment: Hmmmm, I guess that means the plugin is firing before it hits wp-config.php give it a try be using your original code but instead change the path of your files to require_once( ABSPATH . '..\includes\image.php'); that should move up out of the imports directory into wp-admin and include the files.

Comment: Nope, unfortunately the same error... I assume that because ABSPATH is not defined anywhere inside that document it needs to be told where to look for it, but unfortunately i have no idea how to do that or go about searching for it in the WP library. I'm willing to bet it is something really stupid i have overlooked though

Comment: Hey Sam, I meant to have you include the ABSPATH that you had posted originally. I modified my answer above to reflect that. Give that a shot and let me know if that works. If it doesn't, can you post the path it does echo out?

Answer (score 0):

ABSPATH is already  defined by wordpress in the wp_load.php file and is generally the path till public_html or www directory, I don't think you need to redefine it, or use the is_defined to check if it is defined.

defining ABSPATH to current directory is unnecessary complicating things here..

```
require_once( ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php');
require_once( ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/media.php');
require_once( ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/file.php');
require_once( ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/image.php');
```

and this should work..also replaced the backward slashes with forward slash. thats how it works at my end,